# do you see anything unusual with this CAML

Tags: caml-query

I am looking for list items where workflow status equal "Error Occurred". I have the following code and it's working fine. However, there are 124,000 items in my list and the code goes through each item in the list. Is there a way to limit this to items where workflow status (workflow name is "Archive Data") is "Error Occurred". Please suggest. I added following CAML and changed the code but it still returns all the records. I tested the CAML with u2u and it returns 144 records. I added write-host to get a count and commented out the foreach for test.

```
        # Terminates all workflow in a give list
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $web = Get-SPWeb "http://inside.nov.com/sales/SouthEast"
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
    # $list name is list display name
    $list = $web.Lists["New Orders"]
    $CAML = '<Query>
           <Where>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name="ArchiveData" />
                 <Value Type="WorkflowStatus">3</Value>
              </Eq>
           </Where>
        </Query>'

$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = $CAML
$listitems = $list.GetItems($query)
Write-Host "Count: " $listitems.Count

    #foreach ($item in $listItems) 
    #{
    #   foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows)
    #   {
    #       #Cancel Workflows        
    #       [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf)   
    #   }
    #}
    $web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an [`SPQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object, the `Query` property automatically adds the outer < Query>..< /Query> to your CAML.  Try building your query without that, like:

```
$CAML = '<Where>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ArchiveData" />
               <Value Type="WorkflowStatus">3</Value>
            </Eq>
         </Where>'

$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = $CAML
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks Dylan and everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

When using this to query your list in PowerShell (and also c#) you don't include the  tags on the end. So what your looking for would be..

```
 $CAML = '<Where>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ArchiveData" />
               <Value Type="WorkflowStatus">3</Value>
            </Eq>
          </Where>'
```

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds... :)

Comment: well you did write out the `$query=..` part

Answer (score 0):

Do you know there is a CAML Query Helper, maybe you can use it to test your queries: http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/  I think the problem is the value type beeing "Workflowstatus". If I understand you right your query should look like this:

```
 <Query>
       <Where>
          <Eq>
             <FieldRef Name="WorkflowStatus" />
             <Value Type="Number">3</Value>
          </Eq>
       </Where>
 </Query>
```

Comment: I changed the value type to Number but the count is still 124,000.